# Haskell - Pattern matching: How to determine what pattern to use based on two input values

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, wildcard

Okay so I'm learning the basics of Haskell and I recently did a mock exam with a question that used pattern matching and wildcards as part of the function to generate different results. The function created was the following:

```
fun x _ = 1
fun _ 0 = 2
fun x y = 3
```

Now the question was to add **fun 0 0 + fun 1 0** Which both apparently match the pattern that generates 1.

However I can't see how this works, the way I see it, is that any input value could use any of them patterns.

I'm probaly looking at it wrong, so can anyone talk me through this question and why both **fun 0 0** and **fun 1 0** both generate 1? Which when added together gives the result 2 of course.

Comment: Well i'm sorry for that rant, but i've had it in the past before where people litrally downvote for no reason. I'm under the impression this community is very elitist, so I felt the need to protect myself and my reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Patterns are matched in order from top to bottom, so `fun x _` matches anything. The variable `x` is bound to the first argument unconditionally, and the `_` is also matched unconditionally without binding. The other two patterns are not attempted since the first pattern matches.

Comment: Also, the compiler will tell you about this if you enable `-Wall`.

Comment: @Lee Ahhh ok that makes perfect sense, thank you. So, am I right in saying that if the first pattern was removed and there was only the bottom two patterns remaining, the same question of fun 00 + fun 1 0 would equal to 4? Since both inputs generate the top pattern which is 2?

Comment: @Lee Note that if you don't use a variable used in a pattern match on the right-hand side, you can replace it with `_`. `fun x _ = 1` is equivalent to `fun _ _ = 1`.